# How to count selected items in the listbox by just select and see result in a label?

Tags: vb.net

getting the logic of counting is easy but in practice it gets hard sometimes.

[image]

Now I've a list with many items on it. how to count those items if there were repeated and i want to convert that to a number using the FOR loop since i know how many items in the list.

I tried some codes but i did not succeed

```
'''''''''''''''
' VB 2015
''''''''''''
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub lstWinners_List_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstWinners_List.SelectedIndexChanged
        If lstWinners_List.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

            Dim count As Integer = 0
            Dim strselection As String = lstWinners_List.Items(lstWinners_List.SelectedIndex).ToString
            For i As Integer = 0 To lstWinners_List.Items.Count - 1
                If lstWinners_List.Items(i) = strselection Then
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            Next
            lblOutput.Text = count.ToString
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

for EX:
i wanna count the word "michigan " how many times repeated in the list by just clicking on it ?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Do you want to show the count of the selected item in the listbox in the `lblOutput`?

Comment: yes in the label lblOutput. idk what it won't let me post less than 12 words here lol

Comment: Get rid of the `lstWinners_List.Items.Add()` line.  Also, if you're going to loop, then use the **second** version in my post.  You're mixing the first solution, with the second; it's redundant.

Comment: ok i'm using 2nd version now. i removed that line. but i've an error here  (  **   If lstWinners_List.Items(i) = selection Then **  )

Comment: Post your new code.  What does the error say?

Comment: option strict on disallows operands of type object for operator '='. use the 'is' operator to test for object identity

Comment: That's looking much better.  Just change `If lstWinners_List.Items(i) = strselection Then` to `If lstWinners_List.Items(i).ToString() = strselection Then`.  That way you're comparing a string with a string.

Comment: you did it bro!!!! YOU'RE the man thumbs up. now it will take me a month to learn this. many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using Jim Hewitt's comment:

```
Private Sub lstWinners_List_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstWinners_List.SelectedIndexChanged
    If lstWinners_List.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim selection As String = lstWinners_List.Items(lstWinners_List.SelectedIndex).ToString
        Dim wins As Integer = (From team As String In lstWinners_List.Items Where team.Equals(selection)).Count
        lblOutput.Text = wins.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit**

Here's an equivalent, manual, indexed for loop:

```
Private Sub lstWinners_List_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstWinners_List.SelectedIndexChanged
    If lstWinners_List.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Dim selection As String = lstWinners_List.Items(lstWinners_List.SelectedIndex).ToString
        For i As Integer = 0 To lstWinners_List.Items.Count - 1
            If lstWinners_List.Items(i) = selection Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next
        lblOutput.Text = count.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: should i use IF or FOR loop ?since there is 102 teams in total

Comment: Should you use those for what, exactly?  My example displays the count for whatever is **currently selected**.  Are you wanting to separately compute the total for every single entry in your ListBox?

Comment: i wanna do loop repetition, like if i want to count every item selected in the list. for EX: the word "michigan" repeated many times in the list . how i can count that word if i just select it. and that will apply to every item in the list which is 102 words

Comment: It already loops **for you **and counts the selected item. Do you mean that there might be more than one selected item?  Or do you want to write a manual loop?

Comment: Yeah it's looping already..  but it keeps giving me the total number (102)  everytime i select an item. and i'm supposed to use for loop not if statement

Comment: i'm confused here . from where you got the word team ?         Dim wins As Integer = (From team As String In lstWinners_List.Items Where team.Equals(selection)).Count

Comment: On my system it returned the correct count for each selected item.  The "team" variable is a local iterator variable used with the "From/In" part of the linq statement.

Comment: A for loop will allow you to iterate over the listbox, but you won't know if they match without an If statement.  What other requirements/restrictions are being put on you?

Comment: i'll restart my pc and start again. i'll keep u posted thx mate

Comment: 1- insert the list in the collection property . 2- listbox uses indexes. 3- use count property to determine how many items are in the list . 4- use FOR loop for solving the Question.

Comment: so wait, should i put the (IF) statement inside the loop like before the word "next" ?

Comment: Yes, that'd be the way to go.  You'd actually need code like K. Madden posted, except instead of hard coding in "red", you'd use code like in my example to get the selected item and check against that: `Dim selection As String = lstWinners_List.Items(lstWinners_List.SelectedIndex).ToString`

Comment: Did you try my last, posted edited code?  If so, then post your new code in the main post so we can figure it out.

Comment: yeah it didn't work too, i just posted the code i'm using up

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim count As Integer = 0
        For Each n As String In ListBox1.Items
            If n = "red" Then
                count += 1
            End If
        Next

        lblOutput.Text(count)
```

something like this do you mean?

Comment: yeah right that's if i wana count for only RED only, but what if i wana count win for each teams in the list. i'm still using this?